# For the Windows "shutdown" command, is "/p" the exact same as "/t 0"?

Tags: windows-10, terminal, shutdown, reboot

For many years I have been absolutely confused by the cryptic help output of `shutdown /?` (it's not by any means better on Linux/FreeBSD) - (I have deleted many irrelevant flags):

```
/s         Shutdown the computer.
/r         Full shutdown and restart the computer.
/p         Turn off the local computer with no time-out or warning.
           Can be used with /d and /f options.
/t xxx     Set the time-out period before shutdown to xxx seconds.
           The valid range is 0-315360000 (10 years), with a default of 30.
           If the timeout period is greater than 0, the /f parameter is
           implied.
/f         Force running applications to close without forewarning users.
           The /f parameter is implied when a value greater than 0 is
           specified for the /t parameter.
```

Okay, so is `/p` the same as `/t 0`, then? Is it like a shortcut? It seems like it, but it's impossible to know what they mean.

`/p` also seems to imply `/f` to me. But it doesn't mention anything about that.

As a result of all this confusion, I now have ended up with this insane command for "shut down the computer right now":

```
shutdown /s /p /f /t 0
```

I have no idea if it works, because trying it means my machine will shut down (if it works). It feels really bad to have to repeatedly tell it to do the same thing through multiple different flags. I don't get why it doesn't just have a `shutdown now` or something which unambiguously shuts the machine down with an easy-to-remember syntax. (And the same for `restart now`.)

Answer (score 1):

see [MS docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/shutdown): `/p` is equivalent to `/s /t 0`. It does **not** imply `/f`! If you want to force all tasks to terminate you can use `/p /f`. Also, `/p` can **not** be used together with `/t` (or to shut down a remote machine `/m`).